# Multiple NIO reactors, or just one?

Tags: java, nio, reactor

I've currently been reading up on Java NIO and have made some implementations of it myself in the past.  However, I've never really though about the performance of a server -- which seems really silly, and it is.  I've heard people say that a single-threaded reactor is just fine, but I really want to take advantage of the cores that I have.

Since the implementation I'd be making of it is a game, there's some game logic threads as well, so it can't take up a lot of threads -- if anything, it would probably be just two.

Here's the plot that I've come up with:

- High-priority reactor

  1. Accepts connections
  2. Handles the game's log-in process (client sends packet, server processes, server sends response packet, not a ton of data here)
  3. Distributes resource file data on demand (the game is built so the server sends data that the client stores in a cache that contains almost all the resources of the game.  Most of this is done when they are loading the game, but a lot still happens in the background as the play)
- Standard reactor

  1. Reads and responds to in-game packets; these are often small, but there are a lot of them, seeing as just about everything a player does is distributed as a packet, and I want to scale it well to handle well around ~200 players)

Goals:

- Scale well for about 200-300 players
- Respond to game packets quickly
- Distribute the aforementioned file data quickly
- Accept connections quickly

Also, if you are familiar with it, the game is RuneScape.  My goal is emulation of RuneScape's official server software so mine can be used with one of their clients.  It's a popular practice -- see [www.runelocus.com](http://www.runelocus.com), [www.rune-server.org](http://www.rune-server.org), i.e.

My question is:  do you think this would be a good implementation?  Is just having one reactor a better idea?  Or should I be using more?  I would guess the data received and sent would be roughly the same, maybe a little more on the high-priority reactor (which is why it's high-priority.)

Also, when I define it as high-priority, I'm not actually literally prioritising it over the standard reactor.  It's just handling tasks that are considered more important than game packets.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated :)  If there's any clarification/explanation needed, lemme know!

Answer (score 0):

> do you think this would be a good implementation?

For 100 - 1000 connections I would use a one/two thread per connection model with blocking NIO or perhaps old IO. This is often much simpler to implement and almost as efficient for this number of connections. If you have free cores, the simpler you can make it, the better. Obviously this model can use all your cores without a problem. ;)

Comment: So should I just put all of the different tasks into just on reactor and give it a go?  Here's the server's processor spec:  3.1 GHz quad-core (8 threads) Intel Core i7

If I can run it in 1 thread, great, because I'd like to run game logic in parallel :)  My concern is whether or not I'll really be able to stream packets efficiently with one thread.  Player updating packets are often very heavy.

Comment: One thread per *connection*, not one thread per server. No reactor needed. 100 connections = 100+ threads.

Comment: In the RSPS community, people have done that before and have shown that it doesn't work very well -- performance can get a little bad once you start getting to the point of having a couple hundred threads.  Also, isn't it bad practice to make a lot of threads?  What is considered too many threads?

Comment: Too many threads depends on the application, for a CPU bound process you only need the same number of threads as logical threads (in some cases the number of core) For an IO bound application it is more likely to be hundreds, up to one thousand.  Many of these test where one hundred was no good was using older JVM, OS and hardware technology. IMHO the limit is closer to 1000 these days and up to 10,000 is practical with modern CPUs, OSes and hardware. If you want 100,000+ NIO is the only answer.

Comment: Terrible advice in my opinion. 1,000 threads is extremely excessive, especially if you're programming for performance. 10,000 is borderline ridiculous. I would not use thread per client if I expected more than a few dozen clients.

Comment: @BlakeBeaupain Have done any benchmarks to back this up or is this based on experience of using 1000 threads?

Answer (score 0):

As I've explained multiple times on Rune-Server, this is an ideal approach. It is strictly beneficial to the RuneScape protocol (and maybe other cycle-based games).

**The ultimate goal is to avoid and reduce the overhead of encoding/decoding network frames into packet objects and queuing them for later handling.** If you can read directly from the buffer safely while adhering to the cycle based processing of RuneScape and without any synchronization, you have eliminated as much overhead as you possibly can from this task.

The purpose of the second high priority reactor is not for performance reasons - it is to reduce latency for accepting clients and the login process. It also applies well to cache updating which absolutely requires as little latency as possible.